# how fetch function works in cakephp layout view

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and would like to know as how these lines work in Cake

```
echo $this->fetch('meta');
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

Where do the meta tag, css and javascript files that are being fetched come from?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$this->fetch('something');`

According to the cakephp book , the `fetch` function is looking for `blocks` named `something` and `echo` them.

In your example, as far as I understand , it looks for something like that in your view:

```
$this->Html->script('carousel', array('inline' => false));
$this->Html->css('carousel', null, array('inline' => false));
```

and treat it as a block.
so `$this->fetch('script')` will get all the `html->script(....)` and print them.

Read more : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html